# How can I pass on an Exception?

Tags: c#, exception

Basically, what I want to do is pass a specific Exception to a more general Exception within the same try block. I've tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
    static bool example(int count = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            work();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            if (count < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught TimeoutException: {0}", e.Message);
                return example(count + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: {0}", e.Message + " rethrown");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void work()
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("test");
    }
```

I want the `TimeoutException` to be only handled a certain amount of times before going to a more generic `Exception`. This is because the `TimeoutException` has additional information about the exception on a case by case basis.  I do not want to duplicate the code for `Exception` under the `else` clause of `TimeoutException`. The reason I want all exceptions to be handled is that there may be other unknown exceptions that are thrown.  The nature of the program requires it to not crash so I must account for any other exceptions and log them.  How can I implement this?

Comment: `throw new Exception(e.Message);` is _evil_.  You should write `throw;`.

Comment: @SLaks Look at the intent of the code.  He's *intentionally* throwing that information away because it has become an implementation detail of a black box.

Comment: @Servy: The question sounds like it's asking for the opposite of that.

Comment: The question is how to throw an exception from a `catch` block and have it be caught in another `catch` block for the same `try` block.

Comment: Where are you incrementing your count variable? I don't see a count++ anywhere

Comment: @jamis0n `return example(count + 1);` It's recursive.

Comment: You should generally avoid returning a boolean indicating success for some unit of work.  If you want to indicate failure, just let the exception bubble up to the caller, and to indicate success let there be no exception.

Comment: @Servy Any specific reason for that convention?

Comment: @Daniel It results in much less code.  You only need to worry about throwing the exception and catching it when you're ready to handle it.  When you pass the information through return values everything between when you throw it and when you handle it needs to inspect the return value and pass it on.  The entire reason Exceptions were created was to avoid the excessive code bloat this involves.

Comment: I think the problem many are having with answering this is that what you are doing is unusual and messy, because it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: @hatchet No, not really.  This is an appropriate enough way of having a retry mechanism.  I personally wouldn't use recursion, I'd do it iteratively, but that's probably the only significant change beyond what Reed's answer needed to make it work.  It was also answered in 3 minutes, which is pretty much just the time it took to read and then write an answer, so I don't see why he's having problems getting this answered.

Comment: @Servy - recursively calling yourself from an exception handler within the same function seems unusual. Catching a specific exception and then chucking it to throw Exception seems unusual. He assumes the Exception is the rethrown TimeoutException, but it could just as well be catching some entirely different exception (that's not TimeoutException) thrown by work. It just all seems weird to me.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, though for me it feels that there is actually less code being written as is right now, which is one of the reasons that I have it this way. The other is that there are other conditions besides Exceptions that should also return false, and to make that work, I'd have to throw an exception. AFAIK, throwing an exception when there isn't one creates more overhead than simply returning a boolean value. I may be wrong, however.

Comment: @hatchet I actually want to catch entirely different exceptions as well. It's just to log what the actual exception is, even if it's a timeout, after some tries.  In short, I do not want to log the timeout exception unless it has continually failed after x amount of tries.

Comment: @Daniel When there's always a depth of one, you have have some minor performance gains from just returning a boolean, but the issues come from cases where the code that actually handles the fact that there was an error is separated by several layers of indirection from where the error occurs.  The small performance cost associated with using an Exception in such a case is worth the greater simplicity in code.

Comment: @hatchet I specifically said if I were doing this I'd do it iteratively, not recursively, but finding recursive solutions to this problem are still not all that unusual.  As for the outer exception catching other exceptions, that's his intent.  He's returning a boolean indicating success.  Sometimes it's appropriate, sometimes it's not.  You have not merged with the thread of conversation I'm having with Daniel over exactly that point.

Comment: @Servy - I was going by what's implied by the word "rethrown" in this `"Caught Exception: {0}", e.Message + " rethrown"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
bool example()
{
    // Attempt the operation a maximum of three times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            work();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught exception {0}", e.Message);

            // Fail immediately if this isn't a TimeoutException.
            if (!(e is TimeoutException))
                return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to actually do something with the TimeoutException, you could change the catch block like so:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    // As Reed pointed out, you can move this into the if block if you want
    // different messages for the two cases.
    Console.WriteLine("Caught exception {0}", e.Message);

    TimeoutException timeoutException = e as TimeoutException;
    if (timeoutException != null)
    {
        // Do stuff with timeout info...
    }
    else
    {
        // Not a timeout error, fail immediately
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does change the behavior, though - he's got a different exception message in the first case.  (You could easily handle that with this approach, though.)

Comment: If I cast e as a TimeoutException, will it still retain all the original information that an Exception does not have?

Comment: Although this may not be the exact behavior the OP is asking for, the overall design of this seems like a much better/cleaner approach.

Comment: @Daniel.  Casting won't change the underlying object.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just tried it myself just before you made the update and it works. I am accepting your answer because it is a more elegant solution, even though the other answer works as well.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to nest this as 2 tries if you want to handle this this way:

```
static bool example(int count = 0)
{
  try
  {
    try
    {
        work();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        if (count < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught TimeoutException: {0}", e.Message);
            return example(count + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Just throw, don't  make a new exception
            throw; //  new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: {0}", e.Message + " rethrown");
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The "inner try/catch" will only catch `TimeoutException`, so any other exception will always go to the outer scope.  When you rethrow, it'll automatically get caught by the outer scope, as well, which eliminates the need for killing the exception information.  (If you `throw new Exception`, you lose your stack trace data, and other very valuable debugging information.)